# How to add table view cell with a button inside of another table view cell?

Tags: swift, xcode, uitableview

I am trying to make a to-do list app and I am having trouble trying to add subtasks to my main to-do tasks. I have a button inside each table view cell, when this button is pressed I want it to add another table view cell that I can type and save a "subtask" on.

```swift
    //set up tableView row amount
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return taskData.count
    }

    //set up what is in the tableView row
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        //This is for a main task
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "TaskCell", for: indexPath) as! CustomTableViewCell

        cell.label.text = taskData[indexPath.row]

        return cell
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use delegates to pass data from cells to your ViewController, and reload the tableView.

CustomTableViewCell:

```
protocol CustomTableViewCellDelegate: class {
   func customTableViewCellButtonClicked(_ cell: CustomTableViewCell)
}

class CustomTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {
   weak var delegate: CustomTableViewCellDelegate?

   func buttonClicked() {
       self.delegate?.customTableViewCellButtonClicked(self)
   }
}
```

ViewController:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "TaskCell", for: indexPath) as! CustomTableViewCell
    cell.label.text = taskData[indexPath.row]
    cell.delegate = self

    return cell
}

func customTableViewCellButtonClicked(_ cell: CustomTableViewCell) {
     // add the task you need from that cell to your tasks list.
     taskData.append(....)
     //reload your tableView
     self.tableView.reloadData()
}
```